# My jQuery UI code is not working properly

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to create a simple page that record the tasks in a week by entering the task, press enter to create a list item bellow that day. Users can drag task between columns or delete them by drag to the bottom box with id of `#trash`

It just automatically scroll the container when I tried to drag the added li item in a ugly way. I added this code:

```
$("#todoList ul li:not('.listTitle, .addItem')").draggable({ 
  scroll: false
});
```

To tried to make it not scroll anymore, but it does not working

Then I findout that if I add `overflow: hidden` to the `#todoList` in css, the added list file will not make `#todoList` scroll anymore but it does not look the right since the item is hidden. The `.emptySpace` will be at the bottom of the `#todoList` box.

**You will find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/minhha0317/6ph8rgjy/**

Please tell me how to fix this. I am using jquery 3.2.1 and jquery ui 1.12.1. jsfiddle act the same as my actual code on PC

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `overflow:auto` from `.container`.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/6ph8rgjy/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Move you `#trash` inside `.container` like here https://jsfiddle.net/6ph8rgjy/3/

Comment: I admit that it is a good way to fix. But in this case, I don't want it to look like that :)). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Set #todoListWrapper container property like this...

```
#todoListWrapper {
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Changed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ph8rgjy/4/) here

Comment: It does  fix the scrolling problem but then the draggable list item is hidden when I drag it out of the box. Actually I have mentioned that I've tried this method before and not satisfy with the way it hide my item. Anyway, thanks for the answer